# PostgreSQL query with concatenation gives "Internal Server Error" only via AJAX (not on pgAdmin)

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I have the following query in a PHP code (called via AJAX).

```
$q = 'select distinct taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp from spp
        join col on gensp = concat(gen,' ',sp)
        where gen ilike $1 or sp ilike $1
        order by taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp';
$res = pg_query_params($conn,$q,["%$gensp%"]);
if ($res) {
    echo "Works!";
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

`$gensp` is the value the user is looking for (a species or genus name, or part of it). When I run it on the browser, it gives "Internal Server Error" (unless I erase the `join` part). In pgAdmin it works, for instance:

```
select distinct taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp from spp
join col on gensp = concat(gen,' ',sp)
where gen ilike '%Casiornis%' or sp ilike '%Casiornis%'
order by taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp
```

The above sentence also works in psql. I noticed the problem is with the concatenation function. If I use `join col on gensp = sp` it works. I have tried different variations:

```
join col on gensp = cast(gen as text)||' '||cast(sp as text)
join col on gensp = coalesce(gen,'')||' '||coalesce(sp,'')
join col on gensp = gen::text||' '||sp::text
join col on gensp = gen||' '||sp
```

All produce the same error. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.7 and PHP 7.3 on Debian 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need escape quotes here:

```
$q = 'select distinct taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp from spp
        join col on gensp = concat(gen,\' \',sp)
        where gen ilike $1 or sp ilike $1
        order by taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp';
```

or use double quotes like :

```
$q = "select distinct taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp from spp
        join col on gensp = concat(gen,' ',sp)
        where gen ilike \$1 or sp ilike \$1
        order by taxon,ord,fam,gen,sp";
```

but in this case you need to escape the `$` sign for prevent php translation